# lsして得たのポートの名前を用いて、Mac の screen コマンドでシリアル通信をしたい

Tags: bash

USBシリアルポートの名前を調べると

```
ls /dev/tty.usbserial*
```

このような結果が得られます

```
/dev/tty.usbserial-AAAAAAAA
```

この値を用いると、下記で接続することができます。

```
screen  /dev/tty.usbserial-AAAAAAAA 115200
```

Screenで接続する際に、シリアルポートが１ポートしかないと過程した場合
"/dev/tty.usbserial-AAAAAAAA"の値を取得し、
その値を用いてシリアル通信を自動で開始させるにはどうすればいいでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

どういう答えを期待しているのかよくわかりませんが
シリアルポートが１個しかないのであれば

```
screen /dev/tty.usbserial* 115200
```

で十分かと。２個以上あるなら

```
for i in /dev/tty.usbserial*; do screen $i 115200; done
```

とか？ `test -c` したほうが安定かもしれません。

Answer (score 3):

「自動で」がよくわかりませんが

```
screen /dev/tty.usbserial* 115200
```

のことでしょうか？